# Dynamically change iOS LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, storyboard

I'm developing an app using SwiftUI and I have had a default launch screen on my app, using the default `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

However, I want to display a different launchScreen based on information stored on `UserDefaults`.

Is this possible? I assume some workaround is needed, but I have not figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that LaunchScreen has an extremely limited capability, and rather strict guidelines, including that it shouldn't contain dynamic content. Notice this quote from [this page](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen):

> A launch screen appears instantly when your app starts up and is
> quickly replaced with the app's first screen...It’s solely intended to
> enhance the perception of your app as quick to launch and immediately
> ready for use.

You probably want to have a second "landing" screen where you load dynamic content This can look almost identical to the Launch Screen, which will probably only appear for a second at most, giving the illusion of a dynamic launch screen.